# Algolia - Search with a condition to look into an array of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, typeahead.js, algolia

I am using rails and algolia gem with mongoid datastore.

I am sending data to algolia for a model `Question`. One of the doc example in Algolia system is

```
objectID: 5691e056410213a381000000
text: "what is #cool about your name Mr. John? #name #cool"
asked_to: ["565571704102139759000000", "i7683yiq7r8998778346q686", "kjgusa67g87y8e7qtwe87qwe898989"]
asked_by: "564a9b804102132465000000"
created_at: "2016-01-10T04:38:46.201Z"
card_url: "http://localhost:3000/cards/5691e056410213a381000000"
answerers: []
has_answer: false
requestor_count: 0
status: "active"
popularity_point: 0
created_at_i: 1452400726
_tags: ["cool", "name"]
```

I want to find all those documents, where it meets these two conditions:
1) `text` contains `your name`
2) `asked_to` contains `i7683yiq7r8998778346q686`

I am using Twitter's `typeahead` javascript library. And my UI's javascript to implement algolia search is as follows:

```
<input class="typeahead ui-widget form-control input-md search-box tt-input" id="typeahead-algolia" placeholder="Search questions" spellcheck="false" type="text" autocomplete="off" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top;">

$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

  var client = algoliasearch("APPLICATION_ID", "SEARCH_KEY");
  var index = client.initIndex('Question');

  $('#typeahead-algolia').typeahead(
    {
      hint: false,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    }, 
    {
      source: index.ttAdapter({hitsPerPage: 10}),
      displayKey: 'text'
    }
  ).on('keyup', this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#typeahead-algolia').typeahead('close');
      window.location.href = "/?keyword="+encodeURIComponent($('#typeahead-algolia').val());
    }
  });

  $('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
    window.location.href = suggestion.card_url;
  });

});
```

**So my question is:**

This code works perfectly. But how to add condition for `asked_to contains i7683yiq7r8998778346q686` in above javascript to filter out result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a facet filter on the `asked_to` attribute in your query.

You first need to declare the attribute `asked_to` as an attribute for faceting in your index settings and then pass `asked_to:i7683yiq7r8998778346q686` as a facet filter in your query via the `facetFilters`query parameter.

When your index settings are changed, you can change your source to add the `facetFilters` parameter:

```
$('#typeahead-algolia').typeahead(
    {
        hint: false,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, 
    {
        source: index.ttAdapter({hitsPerPage: 10, facetFilters: "asked_to:i7683yiq7r8998778346q686"}),
        displayKey: 'text'
    }
).on('keyup', this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#typeahead-algolia').typeahead('close');
        window.location.href = "/?keyword="+encodeURIComponent($('#typeahead-algolia').val());
    }
});
```